# conditional probability when throwing balls multiple times from a bag

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Suppose a box contains 20 balls: each ball has a distinct number in {1, . . . , 20}
written on it. We pick 10 balls (without replacement) uniformly at random and
throw them out of the box. Then we check if the ball with number “1” on it is
present in the box. If it is present, then we throw it out of the box; else we pick a
ball from the box uniformly at random and throw it out of the box.
What is the probability that the ball with number “2” on it is present in the box?

[image: Tree diagram]

I am unable to assign probability to nodes.please help!!

Comment: Note:  my prior comment was not correct.  The bit about the $1$ matters since, if $1$ is missing, you throw out a random one which might be the $2$.

Comment: If 1 is present that means we don't have to throw any other ball(which can be 2 also), so this might increase the probability of 2 being still in bag, am i correct?

Comment: Yes, that would be the concern. But it's just a matter of working case by case.  The case in which neither $1$ nor $2$ is in the box is irrelevant to us.  You just have to analyze, separately, the case in which $2$ survives the first round of discards but $1$ does not and the case in which both survive.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a start**

We need to see the two cases that need checked:

- the probability that $2$ is in the bag after throwing out a $1$ at the end.
- the probability that $2$ is in the bag after throwing out another number that isn't $1$ or $2$. (Meaning $1$ was one of the first ten chosen)

So we need to first choose $10$ balls that aren't a $1$ or a $2$, which has $\binom{18}{10}$ ways of being done. Then the $1$ will be forced out at the end.

This is all for the first case, see if you can now figure out the second case and continue from here.

---

One more hint: the total number of ways to have this happen (via the two cases) is $\binom{19}{10} * \binom11 + \binom{19}{9} * \binom11 * \binom{10}{1}$

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to solve the problem:

After all is said and done, the $1$ can not be in box.  All the others have the same probability of being in the box and it is guaranteed that there are exactly nine non-$1's$. In other words, the situation is equivalent to choosing $9$ out of $19$ balls. Thus the answer is $$\frac 9{19}=0.473684211$$